# Terminal Services - prevent users from using local printers in remote session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, terminal-server, printing

We have a weird problem that manifests when users log onto a server via RDP and they have the "Printers" box checked in the "Local Resouces" tab of the Remote Desktop Client.  Basically, the server's cpu gets maxed out to 100% trying to do something with a printer.  One proven (by experience) way to solve this is to make sure that checkbox is unchecked in everybody's RDP shortcut.  However, it would be much more efficient if we could disable the ability on the server somehow.  (Better yet of course would be to know the root cause)  Unfortunately, I don't know where to start, as I don't know what this feature's official name is.  I'm not even sure whether or not I've provided enough information for you to help, but I've always had good luck with this community.  Our server is running Windows 2003 R2 Service Pack 2 if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/printing/windows-terminal-services-printing.html
describes the settings for terminal services. You can uncheck "connect client printers at logon" in the Terminal Services Configuration Administrative Tool.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common occurence on W2K & W2K3. When a user logs on to the server, the spoolsv.exe and winlogon.exe processes spike the CPU. The spoolsv.exe issue was supposed to be resolved by a hotfix several years ago, but I still see the issue ocurr on my TS servers. The issue seems to ocurr whether you're using Citrix or RDP. You can control the mapping of client printers via GPO or on the RDP protocol on the TS itself.

http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/guestbloggers/archive/2005/02/22/war-story-the-most-important-spooler-hotfix.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=840371

Comment: +1 Thanks!  this is exactly what i was looking for.  (had to accept einstiien's because he was first)

Comment: Glad to help...